# logic errors in omnibot programming

Tags: python, pybricks-micropython

current problem is that this bit of code is extremely buggy, could be logic errors but i'm not entirely sure, operating on pybricks
orbit1 is movement given in directions 1 - 12

here's the code:

```
def orbit2():
    global current_angle, aligned, new_direction, movetoball
    values = ir_seeker.read(5)
    direction = values[1]
    ir_dis = values[0]
    while ir_dis >= 65: 
        aligned = False
        orbitdir = 2 if 0 < direction <= 6 else -2 #adjust values as needed after testing!!!
        new_direction = (direction + orbitdir) % 12
        values = ir_seeker.read(5)
        direction = values[1]
        ir_dis = values[0]
        print(str(new_direction))
        while not direction == 12:   
            current_angle = hub.imu.heading()   
            values = ir_seeker.read(5)
            direction = values[1]
            ir_dis = values[0]
            orbit1(new_direction, current_angle, score_speed) 
            wait(15) #adjust this as well
            print("orbiting in", direction)
            if direction == 12:
                while movetoball == False:
                   while not ir_dis >= 80: 
                        orbit1(direction, current_angle, 100)
                        direction = values[1]
                        ir_dis = values[0]
                    movetoball = True
        print("aligned to 12, now calculating angles") 
        aligned = True
        break
```

tried everything basically, robot either acted funny or got stuck in certain loops (could be deep nested loops i'm not sure)
help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Do we have to know what you want to do without specify? We are not magicians and we are not debuggers sorry

Comment: yea sorry i forgot to specify,
the robot is a soccer robot that aims to score a ir ball towards a goal
this bit is where the robot orbits around the ball
also i'm mostly unsure about if the logic works or not